# Something like `click_shell` for Typer

Tags: python, typer

I recently started using the Typer framework for command line programs in Python. It's pretty good. When I used Click, I would use the `click_shell` plugin to automatically make an interactive shell for my command line apps, so I could launch them without arguments and get a shell where I could run my commands.

Is there functionality similar to that for Typer?